# can I ask about configuring Server applications on a regular PC

Tags: support, on-topic

I want to ask about something with Microsoft SQL Server configuration.

The question invovles some program not working because of compatibility issue with the version I have of SQL Server, the program and the server are installed on a regular PC not on a Server(The OS is Windows 7 :) ).

Can I ask this question here or does it belong to SuperUser ?

Comment: Tell us more about the environment.

Comment: @MichaelHampton do mean what version of SQL Server ? what information excactly do you need ?

Comment: I'm not Michael Hampton, but for me, it would be more whether it was primarily a SQL Server question or a Windows 7 question.  A primarily SQL Server question is applicable across multiple Windows OSes, IMHO.

Comment: @KatherineVillyard it's primarily a SQL Server question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably answer that question.  I've answered questions about SQL Server on client OSes for applications here.

That's probably just me, though.  When I do, they often get migrated to [DBA.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), along with the associated rep.  ;)

It might be worthwhile to ask there if it's a good fit.  I think it would probably be accepted at [Super User](https://superuser.com/), too, but if it's primarily a SQL Server question I'd try [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 6):

I would vote to close a question that uses a client OS in as a server OS. Other people's mileage may vary.

Comment: does this mean "Ask on SuperUser" ? or is it just you ?

Comment: @niceman It's more than just him.  I'd expect it to get closed with: `Questions should demonstrate reasonable business information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault - see the help center.`

Comment: @niceman I don't know if your question would be suitable for [SU] I don't hang out there often enough to know.

Comment: @HopelessN00b thanks , I've seen the help center but I didn't understand it(I thought my English is good, seems not good enough xD), anyway do you know if it suits Super User ?

Comment: @niceman Not just you, that particular close reason leaves a lot to be desired.  A question like this would probably be accepted over on Super User.